# Getting the last lines that matches a pattern in multiple files

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, sort, cut

I have an application that outputs a set of log files to a central directory like this:

```
/tmp/experiment/log/    
├── node01.log
├── node02.log
├── node03.log
├── node04.log
├── node05.log
├── node06.log
```

Inside each file, different measures are taken during the lifetime of each log's process, so the lines look like this:

```
prop1=5, ts=X, node01
prop2=3, ts=X, node01
prop1=7, ts=Y, node01
...
```

I'm struggling to write some commands that can process all files and output the LAST reading of a giving property, ideally outputting something like this:

```
node01, prop1=7, ts=...
node02, prop1=9, ts=...
node03, prop1=3, ts=...
```

Any suggestions? I started using a combination of `grep`, `cut`, `sort`, `uniq` like this:

```
$ grep -sirh "prop1" /tmp/experiment/log/ | \
   cut --delimiter=, --fields=1,4 | uniq | sort | \
   tail -n 14`  --this example had 14 log files
```

but it only worked partially as in some experiments it would end up printing multiple records of the same log and exclude some other logs.

I moved on to `awk` with this:

```
$ awk -F":" '/prop1/ { print $NF $2}' /tmp/experiment/log/node*.log | \
   awk 'END { print }'
```

and had the problem that when I pass multiple input files, it only gives me the last line of the last log file instead of 1 output line per log file.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: regarding your `awk` , i wouldn't see any `:` in the input file. can you share the exact context of `node01.log` and expected result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at `ENDFILE` blocks (GNU `awk` specific).
You could run something along the lines of

```
awk     'BEGINFILE { a = ""}
         /prop1/   { a=$NF $2 $1}    ## Change this if necessary
         ENDFILE   { if (a != "") print FILENAME, a}' ./node*.log
```

Comment: And there are 3 fields in PO's expected result, but we printing only 2.

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you very much. I was trying to use some begin/end code to make it happen but I think that applied to the entire awk program, where I really wanted it to apply to each file separately.

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU's grep & sed` you could this do this as follows:

```
grep -zoPhr '(.*\n)+\Kprop1=[^\n]*' /tmp/experiment/log/ | sed 's/\(.*\),\s\(.*\)/\2, \1/'
```

**Explanation:**

- `-z` option makes `grep` treat the file as one long string, delimited by `\0`.
- `-r` option will make `grep` recursive
- `-P` option turns on the `Perl` regex flavor.
- `-o` option will select the matched portion.
- `-h` option will suppress the printing of filenames.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, always good to have alternative ways to do things. I gotta say though, holy shit, that's difficult to read!